# Active directory with asp.net

Tags: ldap

I need to integrate the active directory authentication to my asp.net web application.

I am totally new to active directory can some body help me to start this.

Thanks
Inam

Answer (score 0):

This is good link to start up with the active directory,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

I had first confusion with LDAP path du to all that DC/OU stuff, later I used this path LDAP//{domain-ip}. The code on above link will generat full LDAP path for you.

Thanks
Inam